# Disable malfunctioning touchscreen at startup

Tags: touchscreen

My Asus Vivobook S200E has a problem with its touchscreen: it keeps pressing the right side of the screen, even when untouched.

I managed to disable the touchscreen in the Windows 8.1, and the configuration is saved every time I restart the PC. But if I boot into Ubuntu, the touchscreen is active again (of course). I have to run this in the terminal to turn off the touch:

```
xinput disable 'device name'
```

The touch would be off, but if I reboot Ubuntu, the touch is on again, so I have to type the script again at the start of my work with Ubuntu. I find this annoying, and is there any way that I can run the script at every startup?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/a/48327/187281

Answer (score 0):

You can command any command you wich by folowing this:
[How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/187281)

In short:

- Open  "Startup Applications"
- Now click on Add and give in the command to run the application:

  ```
   xinput disable 'device name'
  ```

This will disable your touchscreen at startup, but maybe you can also **explain the problem of your malfunctioning touchscreen** and this problem could be fixed?

Comment: -1. Why would you include an answer here when it's already in another question? Mark the question as a duplicate instead.

Comment: because of my latest edit, It would be better if he explains his real problem and we can fix that

Comment: That should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: But the outhor wouldnt be able to answer as comment, because he is lacking the reputation to comment